# Gets an error during "pip install instabot"

Tags: python, installation, bots

I am trying to install instabot, but I get two errors: "e[error: subprocess-exited-with-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7WOJ.png)" and "[error: legacy-install-failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnhyF.png)". Do you have an idea how I should fix it?

Comment: Permission denied .. Your python installation is probably done via windows admin account and now you are trying to install to that location via user permissions.. Either use --user flag *OR* learn on how to use virtual environments..

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt and run it as admin then run the installation command, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Error: Cannot uninstall 'certifi'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).